# VBA code to transfer only flagged rows of data from one excel worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a RACI matrix in excel which captures lots of tasks, issues and decisions that need to be made about a project im working on, but my project manager only wants to track a few of the items on it. I have a column in in the master that flags these rows.

What i want to do, is that each time the workbook is opened a macro runs in the background that updates that tracker and displays all the columns of data but only the rows of data that have been flagged.

The master worksheet is called: Master 
The tracker worksheet is called "Tracked"

I have managed to partially complete this task using the following VBA code, but when I view the tracker worksheet some of the rows of data are not below the column headers but are at the top of the page and some are underneath the headers (see screenshot). Would appreciate any guidance to fix this so the rows of data only start populating in the free rows underneath the column headers in the tracker worksheet

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Tracked").Range("A13:BN25782").ClearContents
For i = 13 To LastRow
If Sheets("Master").Cells(i, "F").Value = "Yes" Then
Sheets("Master").Cells(i, "F").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tracked").Range("A13").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Tracker worksheet:
[image: image of code output in tracker worksheet]

Comment: Why don't you just autofilter then copy the visible rows ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to declare 2 last rows, for the two worksheets. It is not tested, but it could work:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim i&, LastRow&, LastRowTracker&

    LastRow = Worksheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowTracker = Worksheets("Tracked").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Tracked").Range("A13:BN25782").ClearContents

    For i = 13 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Master").Cells(i, "F").Value = "Yes" Then
            LastRowTracker = LastRowTracker + 1
            Sheets("Master").Cells(i, "F").EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets("Tracked").Cells(LastRowTracker, "A")
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

As you are looping through the `Master`, the `LastRowTracker` is incremented only if it gets into the `If` conditon.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. I copied and pasted the code above and got an error . Not sure what this means, are you able to help me resolve it so i can run it and see if it works?

Comment: @SuzyT - this is because there is no worksheet called `Tracked`. Take a look and change `Tracked` to `Tracker` or vice versa.

Comment: Great, thank you. Thats worked and i think the problem has been solved. Thanks very much :)